# Which term expresses ”a generation of graduates who graduated the first course of a college”?

Tags: word-choice

Suppose business college A first debuted in 2000. It opened its first business course in 2000, and the course will finish in 2004. In 2001 it opened a second course, and students who enrolled in 2001 will graduate in 2005.

What should we call the students who graduated in 2004? Can I say “a first generation of business graduates in college A”, or is there any better term?

Of course, the students who graduated in 2005 are not the first generation of business graduates in college A.

Comment: Foundation corpus?

Comment: the inaugural class

Comment: @WS2 do you have evidence supporting the use of "corpus" for "a group of students graduating at the same time"?

Comment: @phoog I'm afraid not. I was shooting in the dark.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by *course*.  A course never lasts four years. It is typically a quarter or semester long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inaugural - happening as the first one in a series of similar events

[Merriam Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inaugural)

So this could be the '2004 inaugural class of graduates of Business College A'